# Multiple app on MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-console

Is it possible to deploy 2 apps in the same console, both having push notifications functionality for iOS and Androd, one architecture based on polling a database table, while the other one is based on message queue ? I've got MobileFirst 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could... it really depends on though on the application requirements.

The server and console supports the following scenarios:

1. Create a single project with 2 applications and 2 distinct adapters to support each specific way of functionality that you're looking (as you've described).

   Here you need to make sure to have a single applicationConfiguration.xml that fits both apps...
2. Create two projects each with 1 application and 1 adapter and 1 applicationConfiguration.xml.

   This scenario means you will need to deploy 2 war files.